# If the radius of convergence is infinity, does it mean that the series converges for every $x$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've been thinking about it and I feel like it would, but my professor said otherwise. I'm very lost right now because I feel like it's obviously true.

Comment: Yes, it does so

Comment: Yes, if a power series has radius of convergence infinity, then the series converges of all $x\in\Bbb R$ (actually, $\Bbb C$).